# Google Analytics code

Tags: javascript, google

Estou aprendendo a usar o google analytics e me deparei com um problema.
Quero poder colher dados demográficos. No google analytics diz que a opção esta habilitada mas o meu codigo não tem suporte para tal. O código que me foi dado pra ativar o Google Analytics foi:

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'url.ph');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

No [link](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2444872?hl=pt&utm_id=ad) de ajuda ele mostra o seguinte código como "padrão"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxx-y']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;


ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';

var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
```

E me pede para procurar a linha

```
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';` e substituir por `ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
```

mas não existe essa linha. Como posso ativar essa opção de Dados Demográficos?

Comment: Fiz [essa mesma pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19968210/enable-demographics-and-interests-reports-in-universal-analytics) no SOE em Novembro. Conforme as outras respostas, você pode usar o `dc.js` e o `analytics.js`em conjunto (eu fiz o teste e funcionou sem problemas).

Comment: Aqui tem um pequeno tutorial em relação a dados demograficos em português, acho que pode ajudar.
http://dmanalytics.co/habilitar-informacoes-demograficas-no-google-analytics/

Answer (score 4):

O código que te foi dado refere-se ao novo [Universal Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) que se encontra até ao momento em Beta Publico e sem suporte para o `dc.js` que só vira a ser suportado na [terceira fase](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> do processo de migração e implementação.

> **Phase 3: Universal Analytics out of beta.**
>
> - All features (including the dc.js JavaScript) are supported in Universal Analytics.
>   ...

Que traduzido:

> **Fase 3: Saída da versão beta do Universal Analytics.**
>
> - Todas as funcionalidades (incluindo o JavaScript dc.js) são suportadas pelo Universal Analytics.
>   ...

---

## Solução da Google

Na página sobre o Universal Analytics podemos ler:

> The analytics.js snippet is part of Universal Analytics, which is currently in public beta. New users should use analytics.js. Existing ga.js users should create a new web property for analytics.js and dual tag their site. It is perfectly safe to include both ga.js and analytics.js snippets on the same page.

Que traduzido:

> O snippet analytics.js faz parte do Universal Analytics, que está atualmente em beta público. Novos usuários devem utilizar o analytics.js. Usuários actualmente a utilizar o ga.js devem criar uma nova propriedade web para analytics.js e aplicar dupla tag ao web-site. É perfeitamente seguro incluir o ga.js e o analytics.js na mesma página.

## Resposta

Mediante o exposto em cima, podes utilizar os dois ficheiros na tua página, mas certifica-te que aplicas o mesmo *tracking ID* para que tudo seja registado em conformidade.

```
<!-- Universal Analytics -->
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'url.ph');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>

<!-- Google Analytics Demographics -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxx-y']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Pelo que percebi googlando os sites em inglês, você esta usando analytics.js em vez de ga.js. O link que recomenda a substituição baseia-se no codigo de ga.js.

Penso que analytics.js é uma versão mais recente desta API, e provavelmente é possível activar os demographics de uma outra forma, mas para utilizar o link que você colocou talvez o mais fácil seja usar o ga.js.

Esta página tem o "snipet" para o analytics.js, que voce esta usando:
  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/

Esta pagina tem o "snipet" para o ga.js
  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/